# XQuery wrap/truncate on whole word (KWIC)

Tags: xquery, truncate

After spending ages building a custom search function in XQuery (running in eXist-db) I discovered the KWIC (KeyWord In Context) module which has solved most of the problems I had with my code.

I've updated KWIC with the version from [this blog](https://rvdb.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/from-kwic-display-to-kwicer-processing-with-exist/) ([direct link](http://ctb.kantl.be/download/kwic.xql) to the updated module) but there is still one issue I'm trying to fix.

I'm using the following code to display the search results:

```xq
let $kwicconfig := <config xmlns="" width="60" preserve-space="true" format="p" />

{for $match in $results
    let $expanded := kwic:expand($match)
    return
        <li>
            <em>{kwic:get-summary($expanded, ($expanded//exist:match)[1], $kwicconfig)}</em>
        </li>
}
```

which displays the following example result:

> ...nd the interpretation of the criteria. Examiners will be contacted b...

I'm still very much a beginner with XQuery, how do I modify the KWIC function so that the results wordwraps/truncates whole words, and doesn't split words like it currently does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/4pljn6o47nieujav) on the exist-open mailing list, which includes a link to a modified kwic.xql with this feature. A more advanced approach would be to use the built-in kwic.xql function but to use the `$callback` parameters to pass a callback function to the `truncate-previous` and `truncate-following` functions, with your custom trimming logic.

Comment: The modified kwic.xql in your link is perfect, thanks.